# I need to make a boardgame, and each individual tile on a 20 by 20 grid, should be it's own tile class. This is for console at the moment

Tags: c#, arrays, list, for-loop

I am struggling with how to make my board consist of a number of individual instances of my tile class. This is what I've tried so far.

I also eventually want animals to move on the board, but that is for later.

```
class Tile
{
    public int xAxis = 0;
    public int yAxis = 0;
    public string type = "blank";

    public Tile(int xAxis, int yAxis, string type)
    {
        this.xAxis = xAxis;
        this.yAxis = yAxis;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int width = 20;
        int height = 20;

        int[,] grid = new int[20, 20];

        grid[2, 3] = 3;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                Console.Write(grid[x, y] + "");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You never call the constructor of your ```Tile``` class. Maybe you want grid to be of type Tile[20, 20] instead of int[20, 20]?

Comment: Corentin's comment is correct but we can go farther. You make a class `Tile` to represent tiles but you never made a class `Board` to represent boards. People think that ideas like "separation of concerns" and whatnot are too complex for beginners but this is wrong; code is easier for beginners where *every bit of the code is specialized to do exactly one thing*. Make a class `Board` and ask yourself what things make up a board; if it is "a collection of tiles", then make a collection of tiles inside the `Board` class. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you base your project on the design pattern state in order to complete your project.

Since I get you are a beginner, I made you a fully working example you can base your project on, understand it and continue your work to add the animals behaviors your wanted to add.

Here is a game where the tiles change depending on their neighbors and the initial state.
You can see good practices in the comments I left you too.

The GitHub link of the simple board game in C# follows :
[Simple board game project](https://github.com/HugoBounoua/Simple-console-board-game)

Have fun creating your game and I hope I was helpful!

Cheers